# SharePoint 2010 list with paging or XSLT dataview

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am newbie in SharePoint 2010 but have experience in ASP.NET (C#) development. I am currently in a middle of designing the homepage of my intranet portal which will have following webparts.

1. INDUCTIONS (new employees announcments from HR department)
2. NEWS
3. EVENTS
4. BULLETIN BOARD

All the above webparts on HOMEPAGE will be a view based on the Sharepoint LIST managed by their department stake holders like INDUCTIONS LIST on HR page where HR will enter new employees on appointments and INDUCTIONS webpart on homepage will reflect the change. News list will be handled by some other department etc in the similar manner.

I am thinking of building an interface where a webpart will have list with Paging functionality like NEXT, PREVIOUS buttons and on click of any item it will show the particular item in a MODAL POPUP window.

To come up with the similar functionality should I go for

1. Visual Web Part using Visual Studio 2010 and use GridView with buttons.

-- OR --

1. XSLT I mean create DataView using SharePoint 2010 designer.

Please guide me so I achieve my desired results with ease.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always prefer OOTB `XsltListViewWebPart` over any of your custom web part. OOTB web parts handle caching automatically for you.

See this link on how to implement paging in this web part:

http://maulikdhorajia.blogspot.com/2011/06/sharepoint-2010-customize-paging-in.html

Comment: Oh thank you Madhur for the wonderful link but how do I put buttons instead of NEXT hyperlink. Secondly how to do modal popup window thingy.

Comment: Why can't you modify the hyper link to look like a button. Check out this:http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

Comment: :( i am so stupid..gosh i am embarrassed now how come I can overlook such simple thing. thanksssssss...

Comment: One more comment i would like to add..I just read that if I use OOTB XSLT I can't use hyperlinks to the items and therefore no modal popups? is this right?

Comment: No, try to customize it .. its fully customiseable